# node-inspector: debug and step through child_process

Tags: node.js, node-inspector

I have been using node-inspector to step through my code and I like it.
However, I am not able to step through forked processes :

```
... my code ...
var a = getValue();
var b = func1(a);
var command = 'myCommand.js';
child_process.spawn(command, [args], [options]);
```

I am able to step through code until I reach the child_process statement. Is there a way to step into that function and debug the execution of the command ?

Answer (score 3):

Debugging forked processes is not supported out of the box.

You need to:

- Instruct the forked process to start the debugger and to start it on a different port than the master process is listenging. See Node's [lib/cluster.js](https://github.com/iojs/io.js/blob/6ac8bdc0aba5f60f4b4f2da5abd36d664062aa40/lib/cluster.js#L283-L299) for an example how to implement this part.
- Open a new instance of Node Inspector UI (front-end) to debug the child process. You can reuse the same Node Inspector server, just change the value of the `?port=` parameter to match the port where the debugger in your child process is listening on.